# Edit a value after the dataframe has been seperated

Tags: python

I am trying to make a question game where it grabs the questions of the day and shows them to the user, if the user gets it right, that question is moved a day forward

```
    if input_value_variable == 'write' or input_value_variable == 'w':
        system('cls')
        studydata.loc[len(studydata)] = {'Date':dt.date.today(),'Name':input('Please input the question of the item: \n'), 'Description':input('Please input the description of the item: \n'), 'Category':1}
        main_body()

    if input_value_variable == 'q' or input_value_variable == 'questions':
        questions = pds.DataFrame(studydata.loc[studydata['Date'] == f'{dt.date.today()}'])
        system('cls')

        for questionindex in range(len(questions)):
            input(f' \n\nAnswer the question below:\n{questions.iloc[questionindex][1]}?\n----------------------------------------------- \n')
            input_value_variable = input('        Was your answer correct/close? \n         ( y - yes | n - no | ea - edit) \n----------------------------------------------- \n')
            if input_value_variable == 'yes' or input_value_variable == 'y':
                questions.at[str(questionindex), '3'] += 1
```

however a issue i came across was when i showed the questions, there was no way to update the date because the date was in another df (i had seperated the df into a df with the date as today, and a df where the date was anything but), how do i show the user only certain questions yet allow the user to still update the question date if they get it right?

how its supposed to be:

```
I answer a question and get it right
df updates the cell value in the main df
```

how it is:

```
I answer a question and get it right
df updates the cell value in the df with only the current questions of the day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should update studydata df rather than questions df. Whenever you define a new dataframe pandas makes a copy rather than a reference, so even if your "questions" dataframe is a slice of the original it will be treated as a seperate entity.

You should try and find some key that is consistent between the frames (ie; a unique key such as QuestionID) and preform whichever changes you need to studydata where studydata['QuestionID'] == questions['QuestionID']. Otherwise, if the questionindex is consistent between frames, you can just replace questions.at with studydata.at

Hope this helps.

Comment: is the index of the original df saved onto the new df?

Comment: From what I have seen, yes, but I can't confidently say that it might not cause problems. To be safe I would always prefer primary key identifiers over an index if possible but I believe index numbers are not changed unless you explicitly try to re-index the dataframe.